# How to remove multiple line breaks from RSS feed?

Tags: php

How to remove multiple `<br>` tags from a RSS feed? I tried those two but it doesn't make any change.

```
str_replace("<br/><br/>","&",$entry->description); 
str_replace("<br><br>","&",$entry->description); 
str_replace("&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;","&",$entry->description); 
str_replace("&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;","&",$entry->description); (with space)
Here is a sample
```

`This is copied from feedburn RSS&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;with view page source.`

Comment: Can you post some raw output of the lines in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open it in a DOM Parser and look for `br` elements of whom their `nextSibling` (or `previousSibling` if iterating in reverse) is another `br` element (you could repeat this for multiple `br` elements that are direct siblings). Then remove them.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('br');
$length = $elements->length;

while ($length--) {
   $elem = $elements->item($length);                
   $prevSibling = $elem->previousSibling;

if ($prevSibling->nodeType == 1 AND $prevSibling->tagName == 'br') {
       $parent = $elem->parentNode;
       $parent->removeChild($elem);
       $parent->removeChild($prevSibling);
       $length--;
   }

}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lWTpZH).

I chose to iterate in reverse to save another variable used for the incremental number.

I had to use a `while() { ... }` with an index because a `foreach()` would hold a reference to nodes I would be removing, which would result in errors.

Comment: Mr D. Voter, an explanation if you will? Cheers.

Comment: Hi alex, what should I echo ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably getting escaped, so maybe try:

```
$formatted = $entry->description
$formatted = str_replace("&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;","&",$formatted); 
$formatted = str_replace("&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;","&",$formatted);

print($formatted)
```

Make sure you print/echo $formatted. `str_replace` is not a destructive function, so you need to use its return value.

Comment: I think mine is working, but your surrounding code is wrong. You need to set a variable to the return value. I updated my example with an explanation and more thorough code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace more than one in a row, this will do it:

```
<?php
    $entry = "Hello <br><br><br> my <br /><br /> dear <br/><br/><br/> friend";
    $formatted = preg_replace('/(<br ?\/?>)+/',"<br />",$entry);
    var_dump($formatted);
?>
```

This will return:

```
'Hello <br /> my <br /> dear <br /> friend'
```